# How to add javascript functions to divs loaded externally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have page A and pageB.
Page A loads page B into a div.
There are divs in page B that I when I want to execute functions onclick.
The problem is that no matter where I place pageB's javascript it doesn't work.

I assumed that if i had a function ot initalise pagesB's javascript after it was loaded into the div this would work... but no success...

Any responses would be very helpful... regards J

Comment: post some code or a jsfiddle for your problem

Comment: We need to know how you're loading page B into the div and probably need to see the page B initialization code that you want to run.  As your question stands now, it's unanswerable because there's not enough information to know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're loading Page B with ajax, then most likely the javascript inside Page B is getting stripped out. This is due to a security concern.

An alternative way to get this to work would be that you separate your structure like this

- Page A HTML
- Page A javascript
- Page B HTML
- Page B javascript

Now, when you load Page A you should load the following:

- Page A HTML
- Page A javascript
- Page B javascript

Then, when you make your ajax call to load Page B HTML, you simply call the Page B javascript (which is already loaded) and everything should work.

Here's an example of what I'm describing:

http://jsfiddle.net/josephbulger/zSmQE/

Comment: You may want to work on the markup, so this get more clear. Maybe add a sample code with the loading order.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, that was actually how I had it set up... and it wasn't working... but now it is... so there was obviously something else i was doing wrong. thanks.

Comment: @Joseph you did clear my concept. It worked for me. This thing wasted my 3 precious hours.

Answer (score 0):

How are you pulling in the page B? You need to bring it in raw, some methods of pulling in pages actually process the page and return the results instead of just returning the code. This may be part of the problem, but I wouldn't think it would be.

Also, you should be able to just reference the controls in page B and you can use document.getElementById or if using jquery $("controlID").event and wire functions to them.

actually, you could put page B's javascript into an external file and then add it to page A using script src= because once the code is pulled into the page, they are part of the page.